# Show that: The set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, solution-verification, natural-numbers

Show that:

> The set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set

---

**My attempt:**

Lets define the set $M:=\lbrace K : K \subset \mathbb{N}  \wedge |K|<\infty \rbrace$

We now show that $|M|=|\aleph_0|$

For that task we define $A_n:=\lbrace K:K\in M\wedge |K|=n\rbrace$

We show $A_n$ is countable for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

**[IB:]**

For $n=1$

$A_1$ is obviously countable

**[IH:]**

We have shown the statement is true for a certain $n$. We no show its true for $n+1$.

**[IS:]**

$A_{n+1}=A_n\cup\lbrace a\,\cup k:a \in A_n,k\in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$

Since **(IH:)** $A_n$ is countable we can define a sequence $(a_n)$ which has $A_n$ as underlying set.

*Now we define:*

$$\tau_k:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow D_k:n \mapsto a_n \cup k$$

with $k \in \mathbb{N} \vee k=\varnothing$ and $D_k:=\lbrace a_n \cup k:n\in \mathbb{N} \rbrace  $

$\tau_k$ is definitly surjective $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$

which means $D_k$ is a countable set $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$

$\Longrightarrow \bigcup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} D_k=A_{n+1}$ is countable

which finishes the induction and tells us $A_n$ is countable $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

This implies the union $\bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n=M$ is also countable

$\Box$

---

**Would be great of someone could look over it and tell me if im correct, and if not, what to improve :) thank you very much**

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361320/neatest-proof-that-set-of-finite-subsets-is-countable https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612036/is-the-collection-of-finite-subsets-of-mathbbz-countable https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200389/show-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable probably more.

Comment: It seems that you have to be more careful with sets and elements. For example, you write that $A_1 = \Bbb N$. However, that is not true. $A_1 = \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \ldots\}$ whereas $\Bbb N = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$. The two are different.

Comment: a true, but it doenst change the rest, when I fix that aspect, or?

Comment: You didn't show/mention that $A_0=\{\emptyset\}$ is also countable. The empty set definitely is a finite subset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: BTW it's possible to give an explicit bijection: $$f:M\to\mathbb N, f(S)=\sum_{n\in S} 2^n$$ (where I assume $0\in\mathbb N$).

Comment: Or, since all you need is an injection $f:M\to\mathbb N$ to prove that $M$ is countable, $$f(S)=\prod_{n\in S}p_n$$ where $p_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ prime.

Comment: okey but is my idea how to proof it valid? I mean when I fix the details?